# @font-face where does the 'smiley' (src: local('the_smiley_image') come from?

Tags: font-face

I have the great book on stunning css3 and it's talking about using `src: local('a_smiley_image')` and it's showing an actual smiley image being used.
I have no idea what I should actually type to make that appear as it certainly does not look like a ":)"
Is my only option to copy and post from web posts that shows "☺" like that ?
I also know the unicode is &#x263A for inserting into actual html web pages, however I want to use it in a regular editor or IDE on Ubuntu (1st), Mac's (2nd) and Windows (3rd) - because at the end of the day the solution given of using smiley-face for the font implies doing this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on another question so I can past it here and here it is:

```
src: local("☺")
```

Given no other answer I will use this.

Comment: I wonder if it's actually read as a real smiley (as ☺) in web browsers? Because in my text editor (Notepad++) it shows as a question mark > `src: local("?")`